# What servo motor and mechanism to move the whole Raspi, its camera and case?

Tags: gpio, servo

I know there is an interesting Pan & tilt from openelectronics but my project is to move (to pan only) the whole raspi and camera with its waterproof case (# 500 gr) It 's for an outdoor site. as shown here http://ed-venture.biz/outdoor-pice-the-raspberry-pi-camera-enclosure.html
My purpose is to get the camera moving 1/5 of a degree each 5 seconds

Comment: You realise that case will only work in warm climates. In Europe that Pi is going to fry inside the (from moisture)

Comment: Right ! but the site is Africa ....May be too hot ???

Comment: I didn't know you were in "Africa"  :) Yes- Make sure its not direct in the sun or the overheat protection will kick in and reset the Pi. In the shade you will be OK. You might as well buy a plex one and use a bit of silicone to seal it. NO need for this wierd steal box- that isn't even weather proof.They say it is, but trust me. its not.

Answer (score 2):

Use a standard servo, like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0006O3WVE) one. You could probably just screw the servo horns to the bottom of the case (or hot-glue, or superglue, etc.).

Then you can run the servo's wire to the Raspberry Pi's GPIO pins and program it how you want it (probably use a Python Script). For help with that check out [this forum post](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=46771).

Comment: @user3315730 If it helped/solved the problem, you should mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Servo's can do that, but you have to make sure it has enough range. Most won't do 360degrees. Servo's however require some addition circuitry, to make them stop moving. You don't want jerkiness, when taking photos. This will reduce power usage.

Alternatively use a stepper motor. You'll have more precise control angle of rotation. But unlike with a servo, you have to set the start position of the device, as a stepper will only move relative to it's current position, where as with a servo, you can just specify the angle.